# Group array by time interval in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, time

I have an array like this:

```
$data = [
 '12:00' => [1,12,31,212],
 '12:30' => [22,1,31,22],
 '12:45' => [22,1,31,22],
 '13:00' => [22,1,31,22],
 '20:00' => [22,1,31,22],
 '20:30' => [22,1,31,22],
];
```

And I wish to group it by an time interval in minutes, so I need to do a function which accepts this array and a given time interval.

I tried something like:

```
group_by_time_interval($data, $interval // in minutes)
```

And it should return another array like that:

```
$new_data = group_by_time_interval($data, 45);

$new_data = [
  0 = > [
    '12:00' => [1,12,31,212],
    '12:30' => [22,1,31,22],
    '12:45' => [22,1,31,22],
  ],
  1 => [
    '13:00' => [22,1,31,22]
  ],
  2 => [
   '20:00' => [22,1,31,22],
   '20:30' => [22,1,31,22]
  ]
];
```

I`m stucked with this, and I have no idea how to do it, already tried a lot of things with no success.

Comment: And your efforts so far are... ?

Comment: can you provide the current result?

Comment: What if you have a time entry for every 5 minutes in an hour period, and want to group by 25 minutes? How will you decide which is the best cut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over the array (keys must be sorted) and keep track of the first key you added to a sub array. Whenever that key is further behind the current key than the interval allows, create a new sub array, and add the entry there:

```
function group_by_time_interval($data, $interval) {
    $last = null;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // Minutes since midnight:
        $minute = (strtotime($key) - strtotime("today")) / 60;
        if ($last === null || $minute - $last > $interval) {
            $result[] = [[$key => $value]];
            $last = $minute; // Remember first key being stored for new period
        } else {
            $result[count($result)-1][] = [$key => $value];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/844683).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution....

```
$data = array(
   '12:00' => array(1,12,31,212),
   '12:30' => array(22,1,31,22),
   '12:45' => array(22,1,31,22),
   '13:00' => array(22,1,31,22),
   '20:00' => array(22,1,31,22),
   '20:30' => array(22,1,31,22)
);
$new_array = array();
$new_key_value = 0;$i=-1;
foreach($data as $key => $row){
     $new_key = explode(':',$key);
     if($new_key_value!=$new_key[0]){$new_key_value=$new_key[0];$i++;}
     $new_array[$i][$key] = $row;
 }
 echo '<pre>';print_r($new_array);
```

$new_array contains array you want....